# Silverlight Application; How can I add code to a buttons event handler?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, button, event-handling

I'm following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-1-creating-quot-hello-world-quot-with-silverlight-2-and-vs-2008.aspx) tutorial
(beginner Hello World Silverlight Application)

In this step it shows how to add code to the event handler of a button,

[image: http://silverlight1blogpost.s3.amazonaws.com/step15.png]

this is done in a xaml.cs file but i cant find it anywhere,
can anybody tell me where I can add code to the event handler of my button
in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it seems the name of the control created automatically with a new Silverlight project has changed since Silverlight 2 (as in the tutorial you're following).  A new Silverlight 4 project has MainPage.xaml (and MainPage.xaml.cs) instead of Page.xaml and Page.xaml.cs.

To access MainPage.xaml.cs (which is where you'd put the event handler), expand the MainPage.xaml node in Solution Explorer.  This should should show MainPage.xaml.cs under MainPage.xaml.  Alternatively, right-click `Click="MyButton_Click"` in MainPage.xaml and choose 'Navigate to Event Handler'.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I don't see a xaml.cs and the right click navigates me to a xaml.vb file

Comment: @Opoe: it seems you're using VB.NET instead of C#, which the tutorial assumes.  .xaml.vb files replace .xaml.cs files when you're using VB.NET.  There should still be an event handler in the .xaml.vb file, and you should add your code to that.